# Tomcat/SQL Server/Spring - Cast Exception with SQLServerCallableStatement when setStructured parameter caused by JNDI configuration

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, tomcat, jndi

Tech Stack:

- Tomcat 7.0.47
- Spring 4.3.8
- SQL Server 2012

I am trying to implement a DB connection pool in my Java web app and although I have achieve it, I have detected some miss-functionalities when executing SQL statements.

I have tried 2 different approaches with no luck, hope you can provide any clue:

## 1° - Tomcat JNDI resource

Although my connection pool works I lost functionality when using structures as parameters in the callableStatement throwing cast exception from Proxy$14 to SQLServerCallableStatement, problem that does not present with regular dataSource. I have noticed that

`jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500);"` - Cast Exception occurs and JNDI pool connection works fine.

`jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;"` - No Cast Exception but Structure parameter is ignored and JNDI pool connection works fine.

`jdbcInterceptors="` - Structure parameter works fine but JNDI pool connection run out of available connections.

this is my configuration:

**Tomcat server.xml**

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TomcatDS"
    global="jdbc/TomcatDS"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="user"
    password="pass"
    driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    description="SQLServer DB DS"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:1433;DatabaseName=<DB>;schema=dbo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
    maxActive="50"
    maxTotal="50"
    maxIdle="50"
    minIdle="10"
    maxWait="15000"
    reomoveAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="3000"
    defaultAutoCommit="true" jdbcInterceptors="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;SlowQueryReport(threshold=1500);"/>
```

**web.xml**

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/TomcatDS</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**context.xml**

```
<Context path="/">
    <ResourceLink name="jdbc/TomcatDS" global="jdbc/TomcatDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</Context>
```

**spring-db-config.xml**

```
<bean id="sqlServerDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/TomcatDS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="sqlServerDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

---

## 2°- Spring DataSource using Tomcat's DBCP jar

With this way my connection pool connection works weird and although No Cast Exceptions occur, what I have not solved yet is that connections are not released to the pool, instead they are being definitely closed until my app run out of connections. (Disabled tomcat JNDI)

My configuration is:

**spring-db-config.xml**

```
<bean id="sqlServerPoolDataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
        <property name="username" value="user"/>
        <property name="password" value="pass"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://<host>:1433;DatabaseName=<DB>;schema=dbo;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"/>
        <property name="maxActive" value="50"/>
        <property name="maxIdle" value="50"/>
        <property name="minIdle" value="10"/>
        <property name="maxWait" value="15000"/>
        <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
        <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="3000"/>
        <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="true"/>
        <property name="jdbcInterceptors" value="ConnectionState;StatementFinalizer;"/>     
    </bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" abstract="true">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="sqlServerPoolDataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

**DAO.java**

This code is being executed at finally try block of each DB call.

```
public void terminateDBCall(ResultSet rs, CallableStatement cstmt) {
            if (cstmt != null) {
                try {                
                    if (cstmt.getConnection() != null && !cstmt.getConnection().isClosed()){
                        cstmt.getConnection().close();                  
                    }
                    cstmt.close();
                    cstmt = null;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    logHandler.registerSystemEvent(this.getClass(), Constants.SystemLogEvent.ERROR, "La session de base de datos no pudo ser cerrada", ex);
                }
            } 
            if (rs != null) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    rs = null;
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    logHandler.registerSystemEvent(this.getClass(), Constants.SystemLogEvent.ERROR, "El ResultSet no pudo ser cerrado", ex);
                }
            }               
        }
```

**Code that throws the cast exception**

```
@Override
    public boolean updateUser(User userVO) {
        boolean resultFlag = false;
        CallableStatement cstmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            SQLServerDataTable sourceDataTable = new SQLServerDataTable(); 
            sourceDataTable.addColumnMetadata("plantaId", java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
            for (FactoryValueObject factoryVO : userVO.getFactoryList()) {
                sourceDataTable.addRow(factoryVO.getFactoryId());
            }
            
            cstmt = getCallableStatement("UPDATE_USER");
            cstmt.setInt("UsuarioId", userVO.getUserId());
            cstmt.setNString("Usuario", userVO.getUserName());
            cstmt.setNString("Password", userVO.getUserPassword());
            cstmt.setInt("RolId", userVO.getRoleId());
            cstmt.setNString("Email", userVO.getEmail());
            cstmt.setInt("Activo", (userVO.isActiveFlag() ? 1 : 0));
            cstmt.setNString("ModificadoPor", userVO.getUpdatedBy());
=====>          ((SQLServerCallableStatement) cstmt).setStructured("ListaPlantaIds", "dbo.ID_PLANTAS_ASIGNADAS", sourceDataTable);
            cstmt.execute();
            rs = cstmt.getResultSet();
            rs.next();
            resultFlag = rs.getInt("resultFlag") == 1;
            if(!resultFlag)
                logDataBaseError(rs);
            logHandler.registerSystemEvent(this.getClass(), Constants.SystemLogEvent.DEBUG, "The user ID: " + userVO.getUserId() + " has been updated!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logHandler.registerSystemEvent(this.getClass(), Constants.SystemLogEvent.ERROR, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } finally {
            terminateDBCall(rs, cstmt);
        }   
        return resultFlag;
    }
```

> `java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14 cannot be cast to com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerCallableStatement`

Comment: Can you post the code that results in a `ClassCastException`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I have added the code and the exception, I use Structures several times thru the app and it works when I remove the jdbcInterceptors from the context config but pool losses control over the connections, thanks for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Connection` object you get from the pool is not the raw connection object that is connected to the database. It won't be the object produced by calling `DriverManager.getConnection` and son't have type `SQLServerCallableStatement`. Instead, you'll get a *wrapper* object that allows the pool to manage it properly.

It's obvious that calling `close` on a pooled connection would pretty much break the pool, so whatever object you call `close` on needs to instead return the connection to the pool, not close the underlying connection.

In order to get a reference to the "real" connection object, you need to unwrap the connection like this:

```
if(cstmt.isWrapperFor(SQLServerCallableStatement.class)) {
    SQLServerCallableStatement raw = cstmt.unwrap(SQLServerCallableStatement.class);
    raw.setStructured("ListaPlantaIds", "dbo.ID_PLANTAS_ASIGNADAS", sourceDataTable);
} else {
    // Do whatever you need to ; maybe throw an exception?
}
```

I'm wondering if you even need to get a reference to the raw type, here. Can you not use existing JDBC calls to work with "structured" data? I believe the `java.sql.Ref` type is how you'd do this in a vendor-agnostic way. Using "plain" JDBC is going to be cleaner and less fragile than mucking-around with the underlying driver-produced data types.

Before JDBC 1.6, programmers often had to do this when attempting to create new `Clob` objects, and would resort to down-casting their connections to get to vendor-provided methods to create new Clob objects (rather than simply implementing a Clob interface, which had always been possible). These days, you shouldn't have to do this kind of thing, because the APIs should allow you to do everything without downcasting.

Comment: Oh, and upgrade Tomcat. Yours is more than 5 years old with [published security vulnerabilities](http://tomcat.apache.org/security-7.html).

Comment: your response sounds very accurate to what my problem is, first I have tried unwraping and effectively it avoids the cast exception but it looses pool control running out of connections, then I tried upgrading to Tomcat 9 and the behavior is exactly the same, I am not comfortable with the number of tries that I have done yet, I definitely want to try too using  `java.sql.Ref` too but before I need to review its feasibility since this implies a design change across the whole app, but at least I will let you know how the test results were.

Comment: using `java.sql.Ref` works fine, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: Unwrapping the connection should be "safe" as long as you always call `close` on the connection object you actually got from the pool. Do *not* call `close` on the unwrapped connection. But if you can avoid the unwrapping and stick to the generic API, you'll pretty much always be better off.

Comment: I have tried with HikaryCP too and it works better in terms of pooling control and speed, the use of `java.sql.Ref` is definitely the way to go, it works fine and smoother, although for my case I will remain using the unwrapping mode due to the effort and risk of changing it across the whole app.